# React native "Unexpected identifier 'React' import call expects exactly one argument"

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have error in react native app

`Unexpected identifier 'React' import call expects exactly one argument`.

In metro there are no any errors. During compilation too.

I suddenly deleted 'Recent' folder on my Mac and now i am facing this errors.

I already removed node_modules folder and installed all modules again.

`"react": "17.0.1", "react-native": "0.64.2",`

[image]

Comment: Please share the code where you get this error. (Maybe app.js or index.js)

Answer (score 0):

> share your code when you get error App.js or any main file of project

> may be you import wrong thing from "react"